# Disable SwiftUI NavigationView Swipe to Pop feature

Tags: ios, swiftui, navigationview

I am using SwiftUI NavigationView to navigate to three pages.
Navigation works fine, I can go to my desired pages and go back to the previous page using the back button.

My problem is whenever i swipe from the leftmost part of the screen, it pops my current screen.

Whenever I drag from the leftmost part of the screen, my current screen also moves along showing the previous screen from the stack then pops the said current screen.

Is there a way to disable this feature?

[Page Two to One](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41w4R.png)

[Page One to Landing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3JIS.png)

**ContentView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var destinationKey: String? = nil;

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
                Text("Hello, world! Landing Page")
                    .padding()
            
                Button(action: {
                    destinationKey = "pageOne"
                }) {
                    Text("Go To Page One")
                        .padding()
                }
            
            }
            .background(
                NavigationLink(destination: PageOne(), tag: ("pageOne"), selection: $destinationKey){
                    EmptyView()
                }
            )
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())

    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

**PageOne.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct PageOne: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("Hello, World! Page One")
        
            NavigationLink(destination: PageTwo(), label: {
                Text("Go To Page Two")
                    .padding()
            
            })
        
        
        }
    }
}

struct PageOne_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PageOne()
    }
}
```

**PageTwo.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct PageTwo: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World! Page Two")
    }
}

struct PageTwo_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PageTwo()
    }
}
```

Comment: I also created the same ticket on [apple developer forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/704112) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of now, the only way to disable the swipe to dismiss is to disable the back button:

```
 .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
```

If you wish to still have a back button, you can create a custom one with:

```
.navigationBarItems(leading: Button("Back"){self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()})
```

Note: this code is placed in the presenting view and remember to do

```
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
```

in your struct for iOS 14 and before,
or if you are on iOS 15 you can simply do:

```
@Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
```

And simply call dismiss() in your custom back button:

```
.navigationBarItems(leading: Button("Back"){dismiss()})
```

Comment: Using `.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)` did hide the back button, but I was still able to swipe back to dismiss (tested in iOS 15 and iOS 16).